Can a chanter hear his own whisper or muttering of mantra during upamsu japa
I want to know if a chanter can hear his own whisper or muttering of mantra during upamsu japa. Or if the lips of the chanter should move but no sound should come out.

What further detail are you looking for apart from the below answer? upāṃśu itself means in a low voice.

I'm looking for a documented reference. Thanks.

Added. Hope it helps.

Yes, the chanter hears his or her own utterance of the Mantra during Upamshu Japa. The science of Upamshu Japa has been elucidated in Shri Hari Bhakti Vilasa (Chapter 17) from the Narsimha Purana.

sanair uccarayen mantram ishad aushthau pracalayet | kincic chabdam
svayam vidyad upamsuh sa japah smritah ||157||
“Upamshu Japa is performed with the slow utterance and recitation of
the Mantra with a little movement or murmuring of one’s two lips. Thus
the sound vibration of the Mantra is very low and can be only heard by
oneself.”

Digdarshini Tika (commentary) on the above verse by Maha Bhagavata Shrila Sanatana Goswami:

svayam eva vidyaj janiyat shrinuyad ity arthah ||157||
“Thus Upamshu Japa Yoga means that the chanter himself or herself
softly recites, hears and understands the meaning of the Mantra.”

Source for further reading
